# Spring Boot symbol cannot be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a class like the below one.

```java
public class FeedDataFetcherConfig
    extends AbstractFetcher<DataFor, Policy> {

}
```

The problem is in my `@Configuration` class which is in a different module project, I am trying to instantiate it. The problem is it says:

> the symbol `FeedDataFetcherConfig` cannot be found.

Comment: By module, you mean a maven module?  If yes, is the jar built by the module that defines `FeedDataFetcherConfig` included as a dependency in the module that has the error?

Comment: you can define it like this `@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.other.module"})
public class FeedDataFetcherConfig {}`

Comment: By module I mean package